# How do I access `findAndModify` method from Mongo in Node (with Mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is `/models/joke.js`:

```
var mongoose    = require ('mongoose')
    , database  = mongoose.connect('localhost', 'joke', { server: { poolSize: 3 } });

var jokeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  content: String,
  upvotes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  downvotes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  views: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  published: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  author_id: Number,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

var Joke = mongoose.model('Joke', jokeSchema);

module.exports = Joke;
```

And I'm doing this to check if something exist — if doesn't, then create:

```
var Joke = require ('./models/joke');

// ...

Joke.findAndModify({
  query: {
    content: content
  },
  update: {
    $setOnInsert: {
      content: "test",
    }
  },
  new: true,
  upsert: true
});
```

But my console shout me the following:

```
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'findAndModify'
```

I can understand the reason for the error – [I'm calling it through a model instead of a collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#examples), but how do I access my Jokes' collection methods?

I mean, all of the examples were using `db.collection.findAndModify`, but what is this `db.collection`? How do I call it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access `findAndModify` update functionality from Mongoose, use [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

```
Joke.findOneAndUpdate(
  { content: content },
  { $setOnInsert: { content: "test" } },
  { new: true, upsert: true },
  callback
);
```